# iOS app crash when fetcing the IP address

Tags: ios, swift, exception, crash

In my application, I am suing for getting the IP address. Below is the code for getting IP.

```
 func getUrlIPAddress(){
      let url = URL(string: "https://api.ipify.org")

     do {
        if let url = url {
            let ipAddress = try String(contentsOf: url)
            self.ipAddressSend = ipAddress
            UserDefaults.standard.set(ipAddress, forKey: "agent_ipaddress")
        }
     } catch let error {
        print(error)
     }
    }
```

But one crash is reported here in the appstore console.I am not able to reproduce the crash.  Even if its handled with try and catch why its crashing ?
Here is the crashlog details.
[image]

Please help me to found the reason for this crash.

Comment: This code works for me, maybe a race condition?

Comment: Even I cannot reproduce this issue. But reporting this crash frequently in appstore console.

Answer (score 2):

your code works, but it gives me this compiler warning: "Synchronous URL loading of https://api.ipify.org should not occur on this application's main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness. Please switch to an asynchronous networking API such as URLSession."

You are better of using this approach:

```
func getUrlIPAddress() {
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.ipify.org")
    do {
        if let url = url {
            Task{@MainActor in
                let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
                let ipAddress = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
                self.ipAddressSend = ipAddress
                UserDefaults.standard.set(ipAddress, forKey: "agent_ipaddress")
            }
        }
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

EDIT-1: for ios 12, you could try this:

```
func getUrlIPAddress() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.ipify.org") else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        let ipAddress = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
        print("\n---> ipAddress: \(ipAddress)")
        self.ipAddressSend = ipAddress
        UserDefaults.standard.set(ipAddress, forKey: "agent_ipaddress")
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: My application minimum supporting version is iOS 12. So I think I caanot use Task and URLSession.shared.data(from: url).

Comment: ok, but there are other types of  `URLSession`, such as: `URLSession.shared.dataTask(...)` that does not involve `Task`, async/await etc... and is probably available in ios 12. According to the dosc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask it is available ios 7+

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will try that.  Buts why its crashing even if there is try and catch

Comment: Synchronous URL load is probably on main queue and is blocking the main queue. For a quick test, try calling `getUrlIPAddress()` wrapped in `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { getUrlIpAddress() }`

Comment: updated my answer with another option for ios 12.

Comment: @RP89 If the requests ends with a timeout (which is a common situation for network requests), it can block the main thread for too long and the system (or the user) will kill the application because it will be unresponsive (frozen).

Comment: @Sulthan, good point. My sample code does not deal with errors. But you should deal properly/thoroughly with errors  for production code.